# Finding the ring of regular functions on $X-S$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I am studying for an exam of algebraic geometry, and I would like to know if the following is correct.

Let $X$ be an affine variety, and let $\mathcal{O}_{X}$ denote its sheaf of regular functions. Let $S\subset X$ be a closed subset. I would like to find the ring of regular functions on $X-S$.

Assume that $X-S$ can be covered by opens subsets of $X$ contained in $X-S$, $X-S=\bigcup_iU_i$. Then the map of sheafs $\phi:\mathcal{O}_{X-S}\to\mathcal{O}_{X}$ induced by inclusion gives isomorphisms $\mathcal{O}_{X-S}(U_i)\cong\mathcal{O}_{X}(U_i)$ (in fact it is the identity map). Now we have:
$$\mathcal{O}_{X-S}(X-S)=\varprojlim_i\mathcal{O}_{X-S}(U_i)\cong\varprojlim_i\mathcal{O}_{X}(U_i)$$
Now we can always choose a cover by basic opens of the form $D(f)=\{x\in X|f(x)\neq0\}$, so let $U_i=D(f_i)$. Then $\mathcal{O}_{X}(D(f_i))=A(X)_{f_i}$, and we can look at it as a subring of the quotient field $K(X)$. Then:
$$\varprojlim_i\mathcal{O}_{X}(U_i)=\bigcap_iA(X)_{f_i}$$
and thus we see that the ring of regular functions on $X-S$ is given by inverting all elements of $A(X)$ whose zero-set is completely contained in $S$.

Please, tell me if I committed any mistakes, or if some steps are too vague.

Comment: Is $S$ supposed to be closed? If $X \setminus S$ admits an open cover then $X \setminus S$ must itself be open...

Comment: @ZhenLin Yes, I would be satisfied to treat the case where $S$ is closed (and I modified my question accordingly). If however you know how to generalize to more general subsets $S$, please do tell me.

Comment: I guess your varieties are integral. It looks correct.